# Search result return "random number" with search query

Tags: php, wordpress, search, wordpress-theming

Im working on a wordpress theme.
Search engine return me a number with my query search word.

For example: search word "lorem ipsum" 
Title Search result ---> Search Results for: "lorem ipsum47"

I try to looking for the problem, im not sure about this, but here there is the code that i talking about:

```
   <h2 class="title-page page-title">
                            <?php if ( is_home() ) :
                                if ( is_front_page() ):
                                    esc_html_e( 'Latest Posts', 'cize' );
                                else:
                                    single_post_title();
                                endif;
                            elseif ( is_page() ):
                                single_post_title();
                            elseif ( is_search() ):
                                echo printf( esc_html__( 'Search Results for: %s', 'cize' ), '<span>' . get_search_query() . '</span>' );
                            else:
                                the_archive_title();
                            endif; ?>
                        </h2>
```

another point that could help is the HTML that is showed online after research:

```
<div class="container">
        <h2 class="title-page page-title">
                            Search result for: <span>lorem ipsum</span>47                            </h2>
                                                                </div>
```

It's possible that the problem is around this part of code????

```
else:
    the_archive_title();
endif; ?>
```

Thanks for your time
Riccardo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`printf` sometimes is a bit tricky

Change the `is_search` part and instead of `echo printf` use simple `echo` like below.

```
<h2 class="title-page page-title">
    <?php if ( is_home() ) :
        if ( is_front_page() ):
            esc_html_e( 'Latest Posts', 'cize' );
        else:
            single_post_title();
        endif;
    elseif ( is_page() ):
        single_post_title();
    elseif ( is_search() ):
        echo 'Search Results for: '.get_search_query();
    else:
        the_archive_title();
    endif; ?>
</h2>
```